# Call function directly after init

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I have a function, for example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
 // my stuff
});
```

Is there a way to call the function directy after the init?
I know this syntax to call a function directly after the init:

```
(function(){
 // this function will be called directly
})();
```

but how can I adjust my code to do the same (call the scroll-function directly one time after it was initialized)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event handler immediately

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
 // my stuff
}).trigger('scroll');
```

**EDIT:**

per the comments, to make sure no other scroll event handlers are triggered, you can namespace the event

```
$(window).on('scroll.custom', function(e) {
 // my stuff
}).trigger('scroll.custom');
```

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! Is excluded in this variant, that is really scrolled?

Comment: Would that also trigger other scroll-events?

Comment: If you have other scroll events on the window, yes it would! The solution to that would be namespacing the event, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Cool! I give this a try. I didn´t know this namespace method

Comment: This will work with all other .on() events, right (resize, click, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, same principle for all events bound with jQuery, they can be triggered and namespaced if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply name the function before hand and call the function immediately -

```
function myHandler(e){
// your stuff
};
// add handler to event
$(window).scroll(myHandler);
// call first time
myHandler();
// Pass necessary params as you need
// Will not trigger any other event handlers
```

Does this help?

Comment: No sorry, I know that solution but it's awkward because everything has to be outsourced to another function

Comment: Another function? Don't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You have to put every code into another function (in your example "myHandler"). That is awkward! The solution  from adeneo is better I think

Comment: Ok. My two cents - it is good to use anonymous if it the function is not going to be used or required in the scope. Named functions help in scoping and better debugging. Not really sure whats awkward, anyway your choice.